# submit table (dataTables) with checkboxes in header and body to controller through form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor-pages

I have a table with a checkbox in the header (selectAll) and checkboxes in each row. I want to pass the value of the rows checked to an ActionResult method in controller. The string array passed keeps becoming null.

This is my table in View

```
@model List<Models.MyTransModel>

var table = $('#item-index').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx">',
            bSortable: false,
            selectRow: true
        },
        { data: 'col2' },
        { data: 'col3' },
        { data: 'col4' },
        { data: 'col5' },
        { data: 'col6' },
        { data: 'col7' },
        { data: 'col8' },
        { data: 'col9' },
        { data: 'col10' },
    ]
});
```

This is my form : The value I want to submit is @Model[i].Key.

```
<form id="formId" action="FormTran2/Download" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                <div class="dataTables_wrapper container-fluid">
                    <div id="printbar" style="float:right"></div>
                </div>
                <table id="item-index" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="white-space: nowrap; width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" id="parent" /></th>
                            <th>col2</th>
                            <th>col3</th>
                            <th>col3</th>
                            <th>col4</th>
                            <th>col5</th>
                            <th>col6</th>
                            <th>col7</th>
                            <th>col8</th>
                            <th>col9</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                        { 
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox @i" name="Checks" class="cb" value="@Model[i].Key" /></td>
                                <td>@(@Model[i].ActiveFlag == 1 ? "Making" : "Fixed")</td>
                                <td>@Model[i].Company</td>
                                <td>@Model[i].InputCode</td>
                                <td><a href="~/FormTran2/Edit/@Model[i].Key">@Model[i].InputName</a></td>
                                <td>@Model[i].InpDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")</td>
                                <td>@Model[i].CreateOperator</td>
                                <td>@Model[i].CreateDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")</td>
                                <td>@Model[i].UpdateOperator</td>
                                <td>@(Model[i].UpdateDateTime.HasValue ? @Model[i].UpdateDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : "") </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Go to Download page</button><br></div>
</form>
```

This is my controller: The checks array are supposed to receive list of @Model[i].Key in razor, but it always becomes null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Download(string[] checks)  
{
...
}
```

When I inspect the form Data in my browser after I submit the form. It shows:

> item-index_length: 10  
> chbx: on  
> chbx: on  
> chbx: on

When it should be :

> Checks: B00000001:2022-06-03
>
> Checks: B00000001:2022-06-02
>
> Checks: B00000001:2022-06-01

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve it myself by removing this part out from the table:

```
{    
data: null,     
defaultContent: '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx">',     
bSortable: false,    
selectRow: true 
},
```

I think the reason is because this input tag in the table confuses the input tag inside the form. I reason I added this to my table is because I want my table to have a checkbox in the header and I want to disable sorter from the checkbox column.